# Magento 2: Rest api add custom attributes to shipping information

Tags: magento2, rest-api

I added custom attributes to shipping information. I can get them in beckend and order view on frontend.

But I can get it in rest API orders. How can I add custom attributes to shipping information in orders list rest API.

Comment: Which service are you using exactly?

Comment: @MagePsycho I added attribute delivery time for all shipping methods. And this attribute is shown in order view api. But it does not return in list orders rest api. Do you have any information how can i add custom attributes to rest api orders list.